# CakePHP Model Association question

Tags: cakephp

Must association between 2 models be specified in both direction?

Comment: there is no restrictions for no:of words here.so please explain what you are trying to do?

Comment: This question is kinda general and ianmjones has got the answer I'm looking for below.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

No, technically you only need to specify the associations between models in the directions you are going to use. If you are never going to use an association in a certain direction, then you do not need to specify it.